# How reliable is getRange from A1 notation in getRange("Invoices!A1:D4");

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, google-sheets-api

Say I have 2 sheets named Invoices and I need the different ranges using apps script. How reliable is this sort of a A1 notation in `getRange("Invoices!A1:D4");` ?

Comment: The notation that you are using does not include a variable, so it will be constant.  `"Invoices!A1:D4"` is a string value that will never change, it's constant.  A constant is reliable in the sense that it never changes.  There must be something else that you want to know.

Comment: What happens if there are 2 sheets having same name Invoices?

Comment: In the time it took you to ask the question, and then respond to my comment, you could have written the code to find out for yourself what happens.  Your code will need a reference to two spreadsheets if you want data from two different spreadsheets.